# How can I create a new Azure App Registration without the user_impersonation OAuth2Permission?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I was wondering if someone amongst the Azure gurus could clarify the behaviour of the [`New-AzureADApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0). When I create a App Registration in PowerShell, it seems to add a `user_impersonation` under `Expose and API > Scopes defined by this API` in the GUI. When I create an App Registration in the GUI, I provide a name for it and a Redirect URI if necessary, but this `user_impersonation` scope is not created.

I thought that maybe it was something to do with the `AzureAD` module and it's specific connection to Azure AD, but the behaviour is the same when using [`New-AzADApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadapplication?view=azps-4.3.0), with the exception that this cmdlet requires `-IdentifierUris` to be specified too - which isn't necessary for all the apps we register.

Is there anyway to avoid the `OAuth2Permissions` being added when I create the App Registration via PowerShell?

Other things I have tried:

- Setting `-OAuth2Permissions` as an empty list of the type *[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.OAuth2Permission, Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Graph.Client, Version=0.1.599.7, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]*
- Using [`Get-AzureADOAuth2PermissionGrant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadoauth2permissiongrant?view=azureadps-2.0) to try and find the permission and remove it after. It's not there.

*If I cannot avoid this at creation or remove it*, then please provide information on:

- Why this permission is necessary as default.
- Why the GUI doesn't deem it to be necessary.

**Example:**

```bsh
Connect-AzureAD
$GraphRead = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | Where-Object {$_.AppId -eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'}
$RRA = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$RRA.ResourceAppId = $GraphRead.AppId
$ResAcc = New-Object -TypeName "microsoft.open.azuread.model.resourceAccess" -ArgumentList "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d", "Scope"
$RRA.ResourceAccess = $ResAcc
$Test = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "PoshTest" -ReplyUrls "https://visualstudio/spn" -RequiredResourceAccess @($RRA)
```

**Object:**

```bsh
$Test | FL *

DeletionTimestamp          : 
ObjectId                   : ************************************
ObjectType                 : Application
AddIns                     : {}
AppId                      : ************************************
AppRoles                   : {}
AvailableToOtherTenants    : False
DisplayName                : PoshTest
ErrorUrl                   : 
GroupMembershipClaims      : 
Homepage                   : 
IdentifierUris             : {}
KeyCredentials             : {}
KnownClientApplications    : {}
LogoutUrl                  : 
Oauth2AllowImplicitFlow    : False
Oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching : False
Oauth2Permissions          : {class OAuth2Permission {
                               AdminConsentDescription: Allow the application to access PoshTest on behalf of the 
                             signed-in user.
                               AdminConsentDisplayName: Access PoshTest
                               Id: ************************************
                               IsEnabled: True
                               Type: User
                               UserConsentDescription: Allow the application to access PoshTest on your behalf.
                               UserConsentDisplayName: Access PoshTest
                               Value: user_impersonation
                             }
                             }
Oauth2RequirePostResponse  : False
PasswordCredentials        : {}
PublicClient               : 
RecordConsentConditions    : 
ReplyUrls                  : {https://visualstudio/spn}
RequiredResourceAccess     : {class RequiredResourceAccess {
                               ResourceAppId: 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000
                               ResourceAccess: 
                             System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess]
                             }
                             }
SamlMetadataUrl            :
```

**PowerShell Details**

```bsh
$PSVersionTable | select PSVersion,PSEdition,OS,Platform | FL *

PSVersion : 7.0.2
PSEdition : Core
OS        : Darwin 18.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Mon Apr 27 20:09:39 PDT 2020; 
            root:xnu-4903.278.35~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Platform  : Unix

Get-Module -Name AzureAD.Standard.Preview

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name
---------- -------    ---------- ----
Script     0.1.599.7             AzureAD.Standard.Preview
```

**Difference In GUI**

[image: GUITest]
[image: PoshTest]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have managed to work this out so wanted to leave an appropriate breakdown of the answer for others who may also be trying to remove this permission from their App Registration.

I was on the right path with an empty `[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.OAuth2Permission]` list as I had explored above.

If you apply this via [`New-AzureADApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0) *when* creating your app, it will have absolutely no effect.

If you apply this directly via [`Set-AzureADApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0) *after* creating your new App Registration you will get an error like this:

```bsh
Set-AzureADApplication: Error occurred while executing SetApplication 
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Property  value cannot be deleted or updated unless it is disabled first.
RequestId: ********-****-****-*****************
DateTimeStamp: Thu, 02 Jul 2020 10:11:54 GMT
Details: PropertyName  - None, PropertyErrorCode  - CannotDeleteEnabledEntitlement
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
```

So the solution is to first create a new list, add the old scope to it while setting the value `IsEnabled` to `$false`.

```bsh
# New Azure AD Application
Connect-AzureAD
$GraphRead = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | Where-Object {$_.AppId -eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'}
$RRA = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$RRA.ResourceAppId = $GraphRead.AppId
$ResAcc = New-Object -TypeName "microsoft.open.azuread.model.resourceAccess" -ArgumentList "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d", "Scope"
$RRA.ResourceAccess = $ResAcc
$Test = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "PoshTest" -ReplyUrls "https://visualstudio/spn" -RequiredResourceAccess @($RRA)

# Disable the App Registration scope.
$Scopes = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.OAuth2Permission]
$Scope = $Test.Oauth2Permissions | Where-Object { $_.Value -eq "user_impersonation" }
$Scope.IsEnabled = $false
$Scopes.Add($Scope)
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $Test.ObjectID -Oauth2Permissions $Scopes
```

You can finally remove the `OAuth2Permssion` completely by then applying an empty list to it.

```bsh
$EmptyScopes = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.OAuth2Permission]
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $Test.ObjectID -Oauth2Permissions $EmptyScopes
```

Use [`Get-AzureADApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0) to obtain the up-to-date information for the object and you should see that the `OAuth2Permissions` list is now empty.

```bsh
$Test = Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $Test.ObjectID
$Test | FL *

DeletionTimestamp          : 
ObjectId                   : ********-****-****-*****************
ObjectType                 : Application
AddIns                     : {}
AppId                      : ********-****-****-*****************
AppRoles                   : {}
AvailableToOtherTenants    : False
DisplayName                : PoshTest
ErrorUrl                   : 
GroupMembershipClaims      : 
Homepage                   : 
IdentifierUris             : {}
KeyCredentials             : {}
KnownClientApplications    : {}
LogoutUrl                  : 
Oauth2AllowImplicitFlow    : False
Oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching : False
Oauth2Permissions          : {}
Oauth2RequirePostResponse  : False
PasswordCredentials        : {}
PublicClient               : 
RecordConsentConditions    : 
ReplyUrls                  : {https://visualstudio/spn}
RequiredResourceAccess     : {class RequiredResourceAccess {
                               ResourceAppId: 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000
                               ResourceAccess: 
                             System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess]
                             }
                             }
SamlMetadataUrl            :
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is over a year old but i ran into the same problem and found a solution that doesn't require removing the `user_impersonation` after creating the App Registration.

I used the ADMS versions of the PowerShell AzureAD API and found i can get the results i want without unexpected extras:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadmsapplication?view=azureadps-2.0

Use the following to specify the API Permissions:

```
$Resources = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$Resources.ResourceAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" # Microsoft Graph
$Resource1 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "7427e0e9-2fba-42fe-b0c0-848c9e6a8182","Scope"
$Resource2 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d","Scope"
$Resources.ResourceAccess = $Resource1, $Resource2
```

The the following to create the App Registration:

```
$NewApp = New-AzureADMSApplication `
            -DisplayName $Name `
            -SignInAudience AzureADMultipleOrgs `
            -RequiredResourceAccess $Resources
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the permissions is no longer needed by default, but is still present in the PowerShell commands due to legacy reasons.

Please see the code in [Configure.ps1](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/blob/master/1.%20Desktop%20app%20calls%20Web%20API/AppCreationScripts/Configure.ps1) , which locates this extra scope and renames it. You can change it to delete the scope altogether.

Comment: The steps that Ash described are still required: set IsEnabled to false, set the app, clear the collection, set the app.