# Need of scope parameter in Microsoft.Identity.Web downstream API

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using microsoft.Identity.Web package on my .netcore API project which calls Graph API to get the directory objects of the user.

In the appsettings file the downstream api settings are provided as below,

```
"DownstreamApi": {
     "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
     "Scopes": "Directory.Read.All"
   },
```

The relevant permission(Directory.Read.All) is setup in the app registration.

But even if I leave the "Scope" parameter blank the API is giving me the directory objects.

So if the settings is of the format below it still works. Then what is the need of this scope parameter?

```
"DownstreamApi": {
     "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
     "Scopes": ""
   },
```

Comment: how you generate the access token? Show your code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

The scope claim might not had reflected in the token and so you might not seeing any difference with scope assigned.

user_impersonation is the default delegated permission /scope  that exists initially  for every Web app or API in Azure AD.

Please make sure to add the required delegated permissions or application permission in portal.And grant consent if required.

[image]

In your case add directory.read.all Application permission

ex:I added user.read

[image]

Appsettings:

```
"DownstreamApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  },
```

In startUp.cs

```
    Public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            string[] initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');

            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration)
       //  acquire a token to call a protected web API
               .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
               
          //

         //othercode
             ...
   }
```

And in controller we need to specify scopes and send to request headers to get access token for required scopes.

**References:**

1. [call Microsoft Graph  | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/)
   (OR)    [active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2 (github.com)](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph)
2. [How can I create a new Azure App Registration without the user_impersonation OAuth2Permission? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62691947/how-can-i-create-a-new-azure-app-registration-without-the-user-impersonation-oau)

If client_credentials  is the  grant type you may  need to use https://graph.microsoft.com/.default  for scope in the application settings which will give you the permissions defined for  your app.

```
"DownstreamApi": {

    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
}
```

Try to use  /token endpoint in request and  not common

Please see:
 [ASP.NET Core - Call Graph API Using Azure Ad Access Token - Stack Overflow-Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69001458/asp-net-core-5-webapi-azure-ad-call-graph-api-using-azure-ad-access-token)